# How to set up individual Tor connections for each multiprocessing.Process in Python?

Tags: python, process, proxy, ip, multiprocessing

I'm writing a Python script using multiprocessing, that will spawn multiple processes.  It is using the mechanize module to access webpages.  I would like to do this anonymously, so I am using the Tor browser as a proxy.  Additionally, each process should scramble its IP every fifteen seconds.

I found this, which might be useful:
http://blog.databigbang.com/distributed-scraping-with-multiple-tor-circuits/
The primary issue with this, though, is it's use of Urllib2, rather than mechanize, and it doesn't seem easily portable to mechanize.  Additionally, this uses threads rather than processes, so I don't know if it would work the same way.

In short, my Tor is set up to have several different ports with different IPs, and I can set it up such that every process uses a specific port, however, I haven't been able to set it up so that each process uses a different Tor port (ie has its own individual connection through Tor).  And I need to find a new method of switching the IP that doesn't involve switching ports, but this will be easier to figure out once I figure out individual connections for each process.

My simplified code:

```
from mechanize import Browser
import multiprocessing

basePort = 9048 #base port for Tor.  I also have the following ports enabled: 9049, 9050, 9051, 9052.


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.browser = Browser()
        #somehow setup a unique connection to the Tor server?  The port to use is stored in the name.

def Attempt(argument):
    browser = multiprocessing.current_process().browser
    #process argument using mechanize
    #if some condition met:
        #somehow scramble IP

def main():
    global basePort
    f = open(file, 'rb')
    for i in range(5):
        Worker(target=Attempt, args=f.read().split(), name=str(basePort + i)).start()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The following is the code I use to set up a port for use across all processes, but I don't know how to make it specific to an individual process.

```
import socks
import socket

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

from mechanize import Browser
b = Browser()
print b.open('http://icanhazip.com').read()
```

Edit: When I run the code, it says "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'".  But the Process class takes args as a keyword, so why isn't this working?

Comment: So you're writing a scraper?